# Getting No Values in Custom Slots while generating JSON requests in Amazon Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

**My intent Schema:**

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "FruitSlot",
          "type": "Fruit"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "ConverseGenieIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Custom Slot Type:** `Fruit`

**Values:**

```
apple
orange
grapes
mango
```

**Sample Utterances:**

```
ConverseGenieIntent apple
ConverseGenieIntent orange 
ConverseGenieIntent mango
ConverseGenieIntent grapes
ConverseGenieIntent pine apple
```

When i test in service simulator with input as "Mango" or "Apple" i am getting the JSON input request generated as:

```
{
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "SessionId.f11dd59a-d245-400e-b4a0-1398898921df",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.514ba391-33e5-4196-8a61-d140770a13d5"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AEMNWKN5GSRFKMORWJGDBMZ24RZFMNOWM5KWZU4UE2L5S4QUEP7DCXCRD4I6DXMDKVR5P2B3EWO5NAQR7P23R6XRC5IYHM34GFY7S4G3NLSADUQMEN4OJRGE4POSYYAZN53RVP3V7E2DZJJWFREPMLSM7G5Q22LRJGXHWBRTTPDYUIZTMGVNJVG6SHK3WDTNX2BP2JS5GKVCA7Y"
    }
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "EdwRequestId.93fdc778-d0f9-4a3f-8298-295408a7bba3",
    "intent": {
      "name": "ConverseGenieIntent",
      "slots": {
        "FruitSlot": {
          "name": "FruitSlot"
        }
      }
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2017-11-06T11:58:38Z"
  },
  "context": {
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.514ba391-33e5-4196-8a61-d140770a13d5"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AEMNWKN5GSRFKMORWJGDBMZ24RZFMNOWM5KWZU4UE2L5S4QUEP7DCXCRD4I6DXMDKVR5P2B3EWO5NAQR7P23R6XRC5IYHM34GFY7S4G3NLSADUQMEN4OJRGE4POSYYAZN53RVP3V7E2DZJJWFREPMLSM7G5Q22LRJGXHWBRTTPDYUIZTMGVNJVG6SHK3WDTNX2BP2JS5GKVCA7Y"
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

**Why am i not getting any values** in "FruitSlot"?   What is that i am missing?

Comment: You might want to flesh out what it is that you're trying to achieve with all of this.

Comment: Sample Utterances should be **ConverseGenieIntent {FruitSlot}**

Comment: Thanks @PriyamGupta....

Answer (score 1):

As @Priyam Gupta said but now formulated in an answer

Sample Utterances should be `ConverseGenieIntent {FruitSlot}`

the {FruitSlot} indicates that what the user said here needs to be send to your slot called FruitSlot for further checking and eventually sending this to your backend to execute your code.

for example:
i say: "apple"
Alexa will understand this word and check this to your custom type "Fruit" here it will find apple (or not) and will send this word to your backend together with what intent should be called in your back end code.